# Integrating ASP.Net Web API With MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

how to create a web application using the ASP.NET Web API 2 project template and do some data operations like reading the data from the database and calling the Web API Controller method in the MVC Controller and call the adjacent view? any resources for that? I found one but it doesn;t go into much detail

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/integrating-Asp-Net-web-api-with-mvc-basic-infrastructure-by/

Answer (score 0):

The below example provides a detailed explanation on how to call WebApi from a C# app, you can follow same for the asp.net mvc application also

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: any sample projects related to this?